# problems comes here after click on target2 the alert is target2 and on click on download alert is target1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, contextmenu

On first rigth click I am getting alert as tgid as target1 and after click download alert tgid as target1.problems comes here after click on target2 the alert is target2 and on click on download alert is target1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Custom Right Click using jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     var tgid;
 // Menus
 function menu(tgid)
 {


alert(tgid);
var boxMenu = {
    name: "boxmenu",
    items: [{
        text: "|Download",
        command: function() {
                        // This is the menu option clicked
                        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

                            //here is the problem
                            alert("Clicked option 1 and target is: " + tgid);
                        }
                        },
        active: true
        },
        {
            text: "|Share",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },

        {
            text: "|New Folder",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },

        {
            text: "|Paste",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },

        {
            text: "|Cut",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },

        {
            text: "|Copy",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },

        {
            text: "|Rename",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        },
        {
            text: "|Delete",
            command: doSomeFunction,
            active: true
        }


            ]
};
return boxMenu;
 }


// Example function of calling functions outside of a menu.
// Here "this" is going to refer to the option clicked.
function doSomeFunction() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

//        alert(this.id);
        alert("calling external function"); 
    }
}



$("div").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    tgid=this.id;
//   alert(tgid);
    var boxMenu=menu(tgid);

    var newMenu = buildMenu(boxMenu,tgid);
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();

    // Menu not off screen to right
    if ((e.pageX + newMenu.outerWidth()) > winWidth)
        newMenu.css("left", winWidth - newMenu.outerWidth());
    else 
        newMenu.css("left", e.pageX);

    // Menu not off screen at bottom
    if ((e.pageY + newMenu.outerHeight()) > winHeight) 
        newMenu.css("top", winHeight - newMenu.outerHeight());
    else
        newMenu.css("top", e.pageY);

    newMenu.show();
    return false; 
});  
});

// Takes a menu variable and the target element, builds the HTML and returns a reference to the menu.
function buildMenu(menu, tgid) {

    if ($("#" + menu.name).length) {
        var m = $("#" + menu.name);
        m.hide();

        return m;
    }

    // Build overall menu
    var m = document.createElement("div");
    m.className = "menu";
    m.tgid = tgid;
    m.id = menu.name;
    //alert(m.tgid);
    // Build options for menu based on menu variable
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.items.length; i++) {
        var item = document.createElement("div");

        if (menu.items[i].active)
            item.className = "menuOption active";
        else
            item.className = "menuOption inactive";

        item.innerHTML = menu.items[i].text;
        item.onclick = menu.items[i].command;
//        alert(menu.items[i].command);
        m.appendChild(item);
    }

    $("body").append(m);  
    return $(m);
}

// Clears all menus when click the document (as an example)
// Make your own custom trigger for when you want to dismiss them.
$(document).bind("mouseup", function(e) {
   if (e.which == 1) { $(".menu").hide(); }
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#target {
    border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.targetdiv {
    border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}


.menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
    font-family: calibri, arial, helvetica, sans serif;
}

div .menuOption {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

div .active:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #99cb33;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div .inactive {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="target1" class="targetdiv">target1</div>    


<div id="target2" class="targetdiv">target2</div>    


<div id="target3" class="targetdiv">target3</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please also post  your  code.

Comment: We didn't understand anything from your question? Can you explain with your code

Comment: Do you can post your js ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772942/problems-comes-here-after-click-on-target2-the-alert-is-target2-and-on-click-on

Comment: Isn't something what are you looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/ejaF6/1/

Comment: my problem is that on right click every target and clik on download I am getting alert as click on download and target is target1.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8VU5u/ see the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not always recreating the menu. If you reuse it, the `command` event will still point to the previous menu option selected. You need to build it fressh each time:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8VU5u/2/

I also cleaned up the buildMenu code a bit to use jQuery for the menu creation (shorter and simpler).

```
 function buildMenu(menu, tgid) {

     var m = $("#" + menu.name);

     // remove existing menu if present
     if (m.length) {
         m.remove();
     }

     // Build overall menu
     var m = $('<div>').addClass('menu').attr('id', menu.name).data('tgid', tgid);

     // Build options for menu based on menu variable
     for (var i = 0; i < menu.items.length; i++) {
         var item = $('<div>').addClass('menuOption');

         item.addClass(menu.items[i].active ? "active" : "inactive");

         item.html(menu.items[i].text);
         item.click(menu.items[i].command);
         m.append(item);
     }

     $("body").append(m);
     return m;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have clean up my own code.and written without functions.and every time I removed the $("#boxmenu").remove(); 



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Custom Right Click using jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#popup").hide();    
    var tgid;

    // Example function of calling functions outside of a menu.
    // Here "this" is going to refer to the option clicked.
    function doSomeFunction() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

    //        alert(this.id);
            alert("calling external function and target is "+tgid); 
        }
    }
    function cll()
    {
        alert("alert");
    }
    function rename()
    {


      var winH = $(window).height();
       var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $('#popup').show();
        $("#popup").css({"position":"absolute","left":winW/2-$('#popup').width()/2,"top":winH/2-$('#popup').height()/2});




    }
    function menu()
    {
          var boxMenu = {
        name: "boxmenu",
        items: [{
            text: "|Download",
            command: function() {
                            // This is the menu option clicked
                            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                                //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                                alert("Clicked option 1 and target is: " + tgid);
                            }
                            },
            active: true
            },
            {
                text: "|Share",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: true
            },

            {
                text: "|New Folder",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: true
            },

            {
                text: "|Paste",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: false
            },

            {
                text: "|Cut",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: true
            },

            {
                text: "|Copy",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: true
            },

            {
                text: "|Rename",
                command: rename,
                active: true
            },
            {
                text: "|Delete",
                command: doSomeFunction,
                active: true
            }


                ]
    };
    return boxMenu;
    }



    $("div").live("contextmenu",function(e){
        $("#boxmenu").remove();
        tgid=this.id;
    //   alert(tgid);







        var boxMenu=menu();

        // Build overall menu
        var m = document.createElement("div");
        m.className = "menu";
        m.tgid = tgid;
        m.id = boxMenu.name;
        for (var i = 0; i < boxMenu.items.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement("div");

            if (boxMenu.items[i].active)
                item.className = "menuOption active";
            else
                item.className = "menuOption inactive";

            item.innerHTML = boxMenu.items[i].text;
            item.onclick = boxMenu.items[i].command;
    //        alert(menu.items[i].command);

            m.appendChild(item);
        }

            $("body").append(m);


        var m;
        if ($("#" + boxMenu.name).length) {
            m = $("#" + boxMenu.name);
            m.hide();

        }
        var winWidth = $(window).width();
        var winHeight = $(window).height();

        // Menu not off screen to right
        if ((e.pageX + m.outerWidth()) > winWidth)
            m.css("left", winWidth - m.outerWidth());
        else 
           m.css("left", e.pageX);

        // Menu not off screen at bottom
        if ((e.pageY + m.outerHeight()) > winHeight) 
            m.css("top", winHeight - m.outerHeight());
        else
            m.css("top", e.pageY);

        m.show();
        return false; 
    });  
    });


    // Clears all menus when click the document (as an example)
    // Make your own custom trigger for when you want to dismiss them.
    $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
       if (e.which === 1) { $(".menu").hide();
          $("#close").hide();
       }
    });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #target {
        border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .targetdiv {
        border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
        background-color: #ece9d8;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
    }

           table#popup
          {

              background-color:#cccccc;
            border:1px solid #999999;
            cursor:default;
            text-align:left;
            height:50px;
            width:394px;
            z-index:50;
            padding: 25px 25px 20px;
          }
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        border: #c0c0c0 solid 1px;
        font-family: calibri, arial, helvetica, sans serif;
    }

    div .menuOption {
        padding: 4px 8px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    div .active:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: #99cb33;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    div .inactive {
        color: #c0c0c0;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="target1" class="targetdiv">target1</div>
    <div id="target2" class="targetdiv">target2</div>
    <div id="target3" class="targetdiv">target3</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```